# Mobile site not centered on iPhone

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm building a mobile version of a website, using Sencha Touch 2.0, I'm basing the mobile site on the sample app provided in the Sencha Touch Documentation ( http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/first_app ).

I'm testing the app on http://iphone4simulator.com/ just to see what it will look like, but for some reason its not centered, its thinks the screen width is 360px instead of 320px.

I'm not sure how to correct this, has anyone experienced a similar problem ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Actually looking closer at it, I think the problem is http://iphone4simulator.com/ and not sencha touch.